# Ajax with Authentication

Tags: ajax, curl, basic-authentication

I need to create the same request in AJAX.

Can somebody advice me how to include authentication?

i tried user/pass as GET Parameters and change URL to

https://user:pwd@www.example.com/token

i use vue-resource but can also use jQuery.ajax or axios

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pwd';

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/token');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use jQuery's beforeSend callback to add HTTP header with your authentication load:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
```